# Как использовать все процессоры при записи данных в файл используя python?

Tags: python, многопоточность, python-2.x, multiprocessing

У меня есть функция код, который по определенной логике записывает данные в Базу данных. 
Я считываю данные с 2-х файлов построчно и на основании этих данных создаю запись в Базе Данных. Как БД использую ESRI geodatabase.

Но, проблема с том, что для работы мы используем 1 ядро и тратим очень много времени на выполнения этого кода. У меня же 96 ядер и я хочу сэкономить время при использовании всех ядер. Это можно сделать через распаралеливание процессов.

Вот мой код:

Создаю БД и таблицу в ней:

```
 arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management("C:\Users\ivan\CellRebell\ESRI_New_Zeland", "%s.gdb"%Island)
    result = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(
        "C:\Users\ivan\CellRebell\ESRI_New_Zeland/%s.gdb"%Island, 
        "esri_square", "POLYGON", spatial_reference=4326)
    feature_class = result[0]
    arcpy.AddField_management(feature_class, 'ID', 'TEXT')
```

Записываю данные в таблицу:

```
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(feature_class, ['ID','SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    with open('%s_long_double.txt'%Island, 'r') as long:
        for i in long:
                i_1, i_2 = i.split()
                with open('%s_short_double.txt'%Island, 'r') as short:
                    for k in short:
                        k_1, k_2 = k.split()
                        coord = [[float(i_1),float(k_1)],[float(i_2),float(k_1)],[float(i_2),float(k_2)],[float(i_1),float(k_2)]]
                        count+=1
                        row = ['%s_%s'%(Island, count), coord]
                        cursor.insertRow(row)
del cursor
```

Как использовать все ядра для записи данных в файл?
Скрипт написан на Python 2.7.

Основная задача, которую я хочу решить - это ускорить процесс записи данных в таблицу через использования всех процессоров.

Спасибо

Comment: запись должна производиться в один файл или в 96 файлов?

Comment: @MaxU запись должна быть в один файл

Comment: Исследуйте `mmap()`. Тода в основном потоке подготавливаете страницы памяти, а в остальных можете писать в совершенно разные одновременно (ну почти).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450055/how-can-i-improve-my-insert-statement-performance и https://community.esri.com/thread/227719-why-is-arcpyappendmanagement-so-slow

Comment: Вы уверены, что запись (и чтение перед ней) происходит медленно из-за недостаточной производительности одного ядра, а не из-за недостаточной производительности подсистемы ввода-вывода? Как вы это определили (приведите цифры)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


async def gen_values(file):
    for s in file:
        s1, s2 = s.split()
        yield s1, s2


def write(w, i_1, i_2, k_1, k_2):
    w.poly([[[float(i_1), float(k_1)], [float(i_2), float(k_1)], [float(i_2), float(k_2)],
             [float(i_1), float(k_2)], [float(i_1), float(k_1)]]])
    w.record(f'{i_1}_{k_1}_{i_2}_{k_2}')


async def main():
    w = shapefile.Writer(f'shapefiles/test/Indonesia')
    w.field('Latitude', 'C')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=96) as pool:
        with open('long_1_double.txt', 'r') as long:
            with open('short_1_double.txt', 'r') as short:
                async for i1, i2 in gen_values(long):
                    async for k1, k2 in gen_values(short):
                        await loop.run_in_executor(pool, lambda: write(w, i1, i2, k1, k2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Если заработает можно попробовать юзнуть `from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor` вместо `ThreadPoolExecutor`

**Поправил код**

Comment: к сожалению возникает ошибка при выполнении. Добавлю скрин, так как код не могу добавить в комментарий: https://prnt.sc/rqai5z

Comment: @Evgeiy спасибо, код заработал, но ускорения в работе алгоритма не получилось :)